# How to manipulate/scramble/encrypt JSON response from rest API

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, angular

I have a web application built upon Angular 5 and asp.net. My use case is that I need a demo version of this application which must have same UI interface/ Front-end logic but the data/response coming through web api's should change(Data being very confidential so this demo version is intended not to show that data).

I have lots of routes and around 40-50 api's from where data is received. Now, how can I change or jumble all of this data so that original data is not shown to user.

Till now I tried solving it using Angular interceptor, that is to intercept each response and then changing JSON values to something vague. As far as I can understand, I need a layer which can handle all responses and change those response to dummy data. Is this the right approach or we should handle it at back-end using asp.net?

Comment: You can try in-memory-web-api. https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api

Comment: It won't work, as I can't define structure for each and every api response(key - value pairs should be same as the real application, else it will throw error). That would be similar to creating a fake db, but what I want is that response JSON structure remains same with same 'key' but values get changed to something vague.

Comment: Then in my opinion creating DB with dummy data should be fine.

Comment: Changing the data on the client side does not resolve your problem. You may be able to scramble/anomymize the data which is displayed to the user, but anyone opening for instance the webinspector in chrome can see the original data as it is received from the server. Setup a demo user or -- even better -- a separate instance of your backend, containing bogus data. If your data is really that confidential I would not take any risk, exposing it for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Yes I think creating a separate instance of backend in a good option.